# Cant upload LFS objects over 200MB

Tags: gitlab, git-lfs

I'm currently testing git LFS object storage, pushing into an s3 compatible Storage (it's our own S3-System).
Normal upload of files (*.png) works just fine, but if I want to upload a test file of 200MB ( [zip file from here](https://github.com/Apress/repo-with-large-file-storage)), I see the upload go to 100%, fails, and retry until the max retry number is reached.
`client_max_body_size 0` and `proxy_request_buffering off` are both set in the gitlabs Nginx gitlab-http.conf file.

Direct upload into s3 storage works.

Does anybody have similar problems and knows a workaround?
Thank you for your input!

Comment: Check the admin settings for file size limits.

Comment: @systech, sorry for the late reply. 
admin settings (admin/application_settings/general#js-account-settings), max push size set to 1000000 (MB), max im/export size set to zero (no limit). 
Git push still is in a loop. 
If those are the wrong settings, my apologies. Could you then please correct me?

Comment: I'm not sure, but max file upload size might need to be increased if you are not using remote storage (but you're using S3 so that shouldn't matter). Also, if you are using SSH to push to GitLab normally, note that even though you can push non-LFS objects through SSH, git LFS _always_ uses HTTPS on GitLab. This means your git client must be correctly configured to push via https. See [the docs for more information](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/git/lfs/). Also check the troubleshooting section in the [LFS admin docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/lfs/)